# How would you balance this equation by half reaction

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

$\ce{Na + Hg2Cl2 —> NaCl + Hg}$

I was told to balance this reaction by using the half reaction method. I am confused to as how you would do that since the $\ce{Cl}$ is with both the $\ce{Na}$ and the $\ce{Hg}$.

I did with the inspection method and got $\ce{2Na + Hg2Cl2 —> 2NaCl + 2Hg}$ as my answer.

Comment: Half reaction method? It is like rubbing behind the right ear by the left hand.

Comment: Agree with @Poutnik. This could be easily done by hit and trial.

Answer (score 2):

AS $\ce{Hg2Cl2}$ is a covalent compound, you can write those half reactions as:

\begin{align}
\ce{2 Na &-> 2 Na+ + 2 e-}\\
\ce{Hg2Cl2 + 2e- &-> 2 Hg + 2 Cl-}\\
\ce{2 Na+ + 2 Cl- &-> 2 NaCl(s)}
\end{align}

Therefore

$$\ce{2 Na + Hg2Cl2 -> 2 Hg + 2 NaCl}$$